# Websocket connection was closed with code 1006 (AbnormalClosure) on Synapse for altering stored procedures

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, azure-synapse

I am trying to update the stored procedures on Azure Synapse (Data warehouse).

I get this error:

> Websocket connection was closed with code 1006 (AbnormalClosure)

However, when I just alter the stored procedure with less lines then it executed successfully.

Does Azure synapse have limitation on the number of lines which a stored procedure can have?

Comment: Facing the same.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the issue and fixed it, However not sure what exactly caused it. I  tried the same query in SQL Server and Pipeline. It worked in both.

Maybe the issue could be related to the data usage limit in the browser. Not sure.